# array is empty for RouterLink query - Jasmine / md material 4

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-material, karma-jasmine

I think I'm just missing something simple here, but I can't quite figure out where I'm making a left turn.

I'm writing a test to check the links in my navigation menu.  I want to get the entire array of elements and check to ensure that my link is there. I'm using angular 4 materials, angular 4, Jasmine, and karma to run everything you see.

Here is the HTML

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
  <button md-icon-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
    <md-icon class="dark">menu</md-icon>
  </button>
  <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
    <button md-menu-item [routerLink]="['posts']">
      <md-icon>announcement</md-icon>
      <span>Posts</span>
    </button>
    <button md-menu-item [routerLink]="['']">
      <md-icon>home</md-icon>
      <span>Home</span>
    </button>
  </md-menu>
</md-toolbar>
```

The Test code is as follows:

```
describe('HeadercomponentComponent', () => {
  let component: HeadercomponentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeadercomponentComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HeadercomponentComponent ],
      imports: [MdIconModule, MdMenuModule, MdCoreModule, RouterTestingModule, MdButtonModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeadercomponentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should check router link for posts page', ()=>{
    let debugElements = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(RouterLink));

    let index = debugElements.findIndex(de=>de.properties['routerLink'] == "['posts']");

    expect(index).toBeGreaterThan(-1);
  });
});
```

To help out, here's what my debugger is showing me:

[image]

Any thoughts why I'm not picking up all the different buttons with the routerLink assignments?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this post has been up for a while, and some of the Material syntax has changed, but I ran into a similar problem and was eventually able to get it working.  Apparently, the menu is not actually in the DOM until after the menu trigger is fired, and won't be searchable.  In your example test code, you should be able to add the following before your fixture query which, will fire the menu and allow the menu-items to be searchable.

```
const menuTrigger = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
menuTrigger.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
```